Object visualization problem with owner DBA
I'm having a problem viewing other owners' objects, even though I'm logged in as a user with DBA permissions

PL/SQL does not display the view/edit spec & body option

For testing purposes, I created a new user with the DBA permission, and this user was able to view the object without any problems

What could be causing this conflict?
DBA_SYS_PRIVS:

DBA_ROLE_PRIVS:


according to your script, owner_01 already has dba ?  so what do you mean when you ask if that would help?   Obviously  not - since it's already got dba ??  Suggestion: Post a full script reproducing the problem .. create user statement, grant, create object, etc ... so we can see PRECISELY what you're doing  / trying to do ;)

... and don't add that to comments . edit your original post ;)

The question was reworded

what does "select * from dba_role_privs" show on your original user?  (ie would like to see all columns from dba_role_privs - if default_role is set differently between your id, and the test id, that could explain it)

Here is the complete result, in theory the user 'TASY' would have more permissions, but the error persists

If you are able to query dba_objects, dba_sys_privs, etc.... then you most definitely have the privs needed to get everything needed from the dictionary, including package body (from dba_source) without restriction on owner. So this means it's probably a tool (PL/SQL Developer) issue rather than a privs issue on the database. For example, it might be querying user_* or all_* views rather than dba_* views. See if you can configure it to use the dba_* views.
